# Compute $Var(Xe^X)$ when X~Bin(n,p)

Tags: probability

Compute $\operatorname{Var}(Xe^X)$ when $X\sim \operatorname{Bin}(n,p)$

I think it can be solved with m.g.f, but I can't.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: let $M(t):=E(e^{tX})$ so$$M^{(n)}(t)=E(X^ne^{tX}),\,V(Xe^X)=M''(2)-[M'(1)]^2.$$

Comment: @J.G. Thank you for your help. I tried following your hint. But the result is too complicated. $n(n-1)(pe^2+1-p)^{n-2}p^2e^4+n(pe^2+1-p)^{n-1}pe^2-n(pe+1-p)^{n-1}pe.$ Is it any trick to simplify?

Comment: I'm afraid the answer is complicated. Yours is wrong, by the way. For starters, it doesn't vanish if $p=1$.